# How to reverse a negative integer recursively in C++?

Tags: c++, recursion

I am working on some recursion practice and I need to write a program that reverse the input of an integer

> Example of input : cin >> 12345;   The output should be 54321

but if that integer is negative the negative sign needs to be appended to only the first number.

> Example of input : cin >> -1234;   output -4321

I am having a hard time getting my program to adapt to the negative numbers. The way I have it set up if I run

> Example of test : 12345 I get the right output 54321

So my recursion and base are successful. But if I run a negative I get

> Example of test : -12345 I get this for a reason I don't understand -5-4-3-2 1

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void reverse(int);
int main()
{
    int num;
    cout << "Input a number : ";
    cin >> num;
    reverse(num);
    return 0;
}


void reverse(int in)
{
    bool negative = false;
    if (in < 0)
    {
        in = 0 - in;
        negative = true;
    }

    if (in / 10 == 0)
        cout <<  in % 10;
    else{
        if (negative == true)
            in = 0 - in;
        cout << in % 10;
        reverse(in / 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: if (in < 0) return(-1*reverse(-1*in);

Comment: Why don't you just print a `-` and then continue normally with `-in`?

Comment: `cin >> 12345` what?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Console transcript of typing `12345` at a `cin >>` prompt, I guess.  That block isn't pretending to be C++ code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes I changed that part above I only meant that as my test value it's what I am using as a test value.

Comment: Keep the number a sequence of characters.  It will be simpler to reverse a string than a number.

Comment: @CharlesPehlivanian Thank you but the problem states that this must be a void type so I can't use a return statement.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I considered that but the problem states that the type must int and that the function must be void and recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reverse a negative number, you output a `-` and then reverse the corresponding positive number. I'd suggest using recursion rather than state, like this:

```
void reverse(int in)
{
    if (in < 0)
    {
        cout << '-';
        reverse(-in);
    }
    else
    {
       // code to recursively reverse non-negative numbers here
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just just write `in = -in` and full through into the normal code.

Comment: @MartinBonner Normally that's what I'd do, but he's specifically wanting to do it recursively.

Comment: This applied perfectly into my code recursively, but else **MUST** be and else if otherwise you'll get these crazy duplicates where the negative is applied to each number

Answer (score 1):

Split the `reverse` function into two parts: the first part just prints `-` (if the input is negative) and then calls the second part, which is the recursive code you have.  (You don't need any of the `if (negative) ...` handling any more, since the first part already handled it.)

Incidentally, `if (bool_variable == true) ...` is overly verbose.  It's easier to read code if you say something like `if (value_is_negative) ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive function doesn't hold state. When you recurse the first time, it prints the '-' symbol but every time you send back a negative number to the recursion, it runs as if it is the first time and prints '-' again.

It's better to print '-' first time you see a negative number and send the rest of the number as a positive value to the recursion.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void reverse(int);
int main()
{
    int num;
    cout << "Input a number : ";
    cin >> num;
    reverse(num);
    return 0;
}


void reverse(int in)
{
    bool negative = false;
    if (in < 0)
    {
        in = 0 - in;
        negative = true;
    }

    if (in / 10 == 0)
        cout <<  in % 10;
    else{
        if (negative == true) {
            cout << '-';
            negative = false;
        }
        cout << in % 10;
        reverse(in / 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int reverse(long int x) {
     
long int reversedNumber = 0, remainder;
           bool isNegative = false;
    
    
    if (x <0){
        isNegative = true;
         x *= -1;
    }



while(x > 0) {
    remainder = x%10;
    reversedNumber = reversedNumber*10 + remainder;
    x= x/10;
    
}
    
    if  (isNegative) {
        
        if (reversedNumber > INT_MAX){
            return 0;
        }
        else
            return reversedNumber*(-1);
        
    }
         
    
    else 
    {
        if (reversedNumber > INT_MAX){
        
         return 0;
    }
        else 
            return reversedNumber;
        
    }
         

   
    
}
```